# Calculate streak from right-to-left across a row?

Tags: google-sheets

Everyone,

I have this Google Sheet:

[Screenshot of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRG0x.png)

Each row refers to event attendance. Did they attend, yes or no.

For each row, I would like to calculate two things:

(1) How many sessions someone has not joined (so calculate the number of No's from the right until a Yes.)
(2) How many sessions someone has joined without missing one (so calculate the number of Yes' from the right until a No.)

Ideally I would like to detect the further-most column if possible (as I am adding columns with each event), but I set a manual range too if needed - although it would need to ignore cells with no entry ideally.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

I tried using COUNTIF but I couldn't figure out how to count from the right columns to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Count 'Yes' from left to Right

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B3:"&ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(), 4)), "YES")
```

Count 'NO' from Left to Right

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B2:"&ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(), 4)), "NO")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to count from right to left...how would I adjust this?

Also, which cell should B3/B2 be referring to? The far left set of the range?